# Select from 3 table along max id, what use leftjoin or subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

i want select for all row in table zakazka with newest idStavZakazky. How to get it?
**EER Diagram:**
[image]

And after easy left join

```
 SELECT `zakazka`.`idZakazka`,
`stavzakazky`.`idStavZakazky`,
`stavzakazky`.`Zakazka_idZakazka`,
`seznamstavu`.`Nazev`
FROM `autoservis`.`zakazka`
LEFT JOIN `autoservis`.`stavzakazky` ON `zakazka`.`idZakazka` = `stavzakazky`.`Zakazka_idZakazka`
LEFT JOIN `autoservis`.`seznamstavu` ON `stavzakazky`.`SeznamStavu_idSeznamStavu` = `seznamstavu`.`idSeznamStavu`
ORDER BY `zakazka`.`idZakazka`;
```

**Output:**

```
idZakazka|idStavZakazky|Zakazka_idZakazka|Nazev
_____________________________________________________
        1|            2|                1|Založeno
_____________________________________________________
        1|            3|                1|Přiřazeno
_____________________________________________________
        2|            4|                2|Pozastavená
_____________________________________________________
        2|            5|                2|Přiřazeno
```

But i want result like this, show only with newest idStavZakazky

```
idZakazka|idStavZakazky|Zakazka_idZakazka|Nazev
_____________________________________________________
        1|            3|                1|Přiřazeno
_____________________________________________________
        2|            5|                2|Přiřazeno
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the max `idStavZakazky` for each `Zakazka_idZakazkam` in the `stavzakazky` table and then the corresponding rows from the original table (since you need `Nazev` column) and then do the left joining.

Like this:

```
select zakazka.idZakazka,
    stavzakazky.idStavZakazky,
    stavzakazky.Zakazka_idZakazka,
    seznamstavu.Nazev
from autoservis.zakazka
left join (
    select *
    from autoservis.stavzakazky
    join (
        select Zakazka_idZakazkam, max(idStavZakazky) as idStavZakazky
        from autoservis.stavzakazky
        group by Zakazka_idZakazkam
        ) t using (Zakazka_idZakazkam, idStavZakazky)
    ) stavzakazky on zakazka.idZakazka = stavzakazky.Zakazka_idZakazka
left join autoservis.seznamstavu on stavzakazky.SeznamStavu_idSeznamStavu = seznamstavu.idSeznamStavu
order by zakazka.idZakazka;
```